# Easily changing Conda environment (in Win7 64) by renaming folder method? acceptable?

Tags: environment-variables, windows-7-x64, py2exe, python-3.4, conda

Is this absolutely genius method of changing conda environments going to break something later on?

So I didn't have the patience to read through and digest all the mumbo jumbo of changing conda environments. (i'm not even sure my usage of the term "environment" is correct).

I was trying to install py2exe (pip install py2exe) and I got an error and in the traceback I noticed that pip was using my old 2.7 anaconda python located in E:\Anaconda.  My "new" or current 3.4 anaconda python is located in E:\Anaconda3...

So what i did was rename my E:\Anaconda folder to E:\poopAnaconda using windows explorer (right click, rename, etc.; using win7 64).  Then in cmd prompt I typed

```
E:\Anaconda3>conda info -a
```

And then magically after renaming, conda info is now showing 3.4.1.final.0 as my python version and my environment is now successfully at E:\Anaconda3 !!!  (you can see it about midway through the cmd output)

There was a slight pause after hitting enter (for conda info -a) and then the info displayed.  The only difference I can see in the output is some warning about licenses pfffffff

Also both my anaconda folders are listed in PATH:

```
...E:\Anaconda;E:\Anaconda\Scripts;E:\Anaconda3;E:\Anaconda3\Scripts
```

[In the FAQ](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/faq.html#env-creating), there are 8 different ways to activate and/or create an environment and none of those are as easy as this one.

So, is this a "bad" way of changing conda environments? I mean it works so far. But, why did it work?

**Before my genious breakthrough:**

```
E:\Anaconda3>conda info -a
Current conda install:

             platform : win-64
        conda version : 3.8.4
  conda-build version : 1.8.2
       python version : 2.7.8.final.0
     requests version : 2.5.1
     root environment : E:\Anaconda  (writable)
  default environment : E:\Anaconda
     envs directories : E:\Anaconda\envs
        package cache : E:\Anaconda\pkgs
         channel URLs : http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/
                        http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                        http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
                        http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
          config file : None
    is foreign system : False

# conda environments:
#
root                  *  E:\Anaconda

sys.version: 2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)| (default...
sys.prefix: E:\Anaconda
sys.executable: E:\Anaconda\python.exe
conda location: E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda
conda-build: E:\Anaconda\Scripts\conda-build.exe
conda-convert: E:\Anaconda\Scripts\conda-convert.exe
conda-develop: E:\Anaconda\Scripts\conda-develop.exe
conda-env: E:\Anaconda\Scripts\conda-env.exe
conda-index: E:\Anaconda\Scripts\conda-index.exe
conda-metapackage: E:\Anaconda\Scripts\conda-metapackage.exe
conda-pipbuild: E:\Anaconda\Scripts\conda-pipbuild.exe
conda-skeleton: E:\Anaconda\Scripts\conda-skeleton.exe
user site dirs:

CIO_TEST: <not set>
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV: <not set>
CONDA_ENVS_PATH: <not set>
PATH: C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsP
owerShell\v1.0\;e:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;e:\Program Files\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;E:\Python34_64bit;E:\Anaconda;E:\Anaconda\Scripts;E:\Anaconda3;E:\Anaconda3\Scripts
PYTHONHOME: <not set>
PYTHONPATH: <not set>

License directories:
    C:\Users\Kardo Paska\.continuum
    C:\Users\Kardo Paska\AppData\Roaming\Continuum
    E:\Anaconda\licenses
License files (license*.txt):
Package/feature end dates:
E:\Anaconda3>
```

**And after:**

```
E:\Anaconda3>conda info -a
Current conda install:

             platform : win-64
        conda version : 3.7.0
  conda-build version : 1.8.2
       python version : 3.4.1.final.0
     requests version : 2.4.1
     root environment : E:\Anaconda3  (writable)
  default environment : E:\Anaconda3
     envs directories : E:\Anaconda3\envs
        package cache : E:\Anaconda3\pkgs
         channel URLs : http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/
                        http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
          config file : None
    is foreign system : False

# conda environments:
#
root                  *  E:\Anaconda3

sys.version: 3.4.1 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)| (default...
sys.prefix: E:\Anaconda3
sys.executable: E:\Anaconda3\python.exe
conda location: E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda
conda-build: E:\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-build.exe
conda-convert: E:\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-convert.exe
conda-develop: E:\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-develop.exe
conda-index: E:\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-index.exe
conda-metapackage: E:\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-metapackage.exe
conda-pipbuild: E:\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-pipbuild.exe
conda-skeleton: E:\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-skeleton.exe
user site dirs:

CIO_TEST: <not set>
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV: <not set>
CONDA_ENVS_PATH: <not set>
PATH: C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsP
owerShell\v1.0\;e:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;e:\Program Files\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;E:\Python34_64bit;E:\Anaconda;E:\Anaconda\Scripts;E:\Anaconda3;E:\Anaconda3\Scripts
PYTHONHOME: <not set>
PYTHONPATH: <not set>

WARNING: could not import _license.show_info
# try:
# $ conda install -n root _license
E:\Anaconda3>
```

NICE!!

```
E:\Anaconda3>pip install py2exe
Downloading/unpacking py2exe
Installing collected packages: py2exe
Successfully installed py2exe
Cleaning up...

E:\Anaconda3>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work, but I wouldn't recommend it.

In the context of conda environments, "activating" an environment just means putting that environment to the front of your `PATH`, so that programs from that environment get picked up first when you type them. Putting multiple things on your `PATH` and moving them works too, because nonexistant paths are just skipped when the `PATH` is searched.

First off, you shouldn't install Anaconda twice. Rather, use conda to create additional environments.

- **You aren't making use of conda**: One of the strengths of Anaconda is the conda package manager, which manages the environments. It would be better to pick one of your Anaconda installations as the base one and create the other one as a conda environment (e.g., if you pick Anaconda3 as your base create a Python 2 environment with `conda create -n py2 python=2 anaconda`). Then `activate py2` and `deactivate`.
- **If you use conda, you can get confused**: Each installation of Anaconda has a different conda installed. This means to manage each one, you'll need to use the conda that is in that one. Using the wrong conda could lead to issues (it's not really supported). With one Anaconda and environments, you can use `conda install -n envname` and it will do the right thing, because there will only be one conda.

But even ignoring that, regarding your genius idea, some issues would be:

- **`PATH` "leak through"**: If you have both Anaconda and Anaconda3 on your `PATH` and something is installed in the second but not the first, it will pick up the Anaconda3 one (because the way `PATH` works is it searches all the directories for the command until it finds it). On OS X and Linux `source activate` will remove the root environment from the `PATH` to prevent this from happening. This doesn't happen yet on Windows but we want to change it.
- **Inconvenience**: Is moving a directory around really easier than typing `activate envname`? Also consider that if you create a new environment, you will have to add it to the `PATH` for this trick to work. If you make good use of conda, you'll be making many environments.
- **You might break the environment**: This is not entirely true for Windows, at least for most packages. It is very true on OS X and Linux. Moving an environment can break it, because there are hard-coded paths in places. So things in your poopAnaconda directory might not work until you name it bake to Anaconda.

Comment: How should I have installed Anaconda for Python 3.4? I downloaded and installed Anaconda-2.1.0-Windows-x86_64.exe not realizing it was for old Python 2.  So I found & installed Anaconda3-2.1.0-Windows-x86_64.exe, was there a way to get anaconda for Python 3.4 w/o having installed Anaconda3-2.1.0-Windows-x86_64.exe? (assuming Anaconda-2.1.0-Windows-x86_64.exe was installed)

Comment: `conda create -n py3 python=3 anaconda` will create a conda environment called `py3` with the Python 3 version of Anaconda.

Comment: so creating the environment will download and install other versions of python? e.g., let's say there is a Python 4, i would `conda create -n py4 python=4 anaconda` and then bam I'd be able to use Python 4?

Comment: Yep. Conda takes care of all these details for you.